# Is there an alternative to Adobe AfterEffects?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a After Effects like software for Ubuntu (or for free)

Adobe After Effects is a compositing, compositional and post-production video tool. If you think about green-screening, those cool titles/credits, overlays with people's names, infographics... it's all that stuff, and a lot more. Like motion photoshop, in full hd.

Comment: @sepp2k: I think After Effects is well known enough that it's not necessary.

Comment: as sepp2k said, more details wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: After Effects is a compositing, compositional and post-production video tool. If that doesn't mean anything to you, then think about green-screening, those cool titles/credits, overlays with people's names, infographics... it's all that stuff, and a lot more. Like motion photoshop, in full hd.

Comment: vote up danp comment please, because its the true and very usefull. I work with AE (After Effects) and wanna see this question growing up. JFR should copy this into his question too, imho. @danp

Comment: What After Effects does is also called "finishing" and "motion design". Also can do "colorism" and "rotoscope". And near more than infinite things with plug-ins.

Comment: Also some point about what you want to do with this AE alternative will help to better answers.

Comment: @hellocatfood: I think merging would be better considering that both have many valid but very different answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is lots of **high end** (and sometimes quite expensive) video software for linux.

There is a [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software) that has a list of available software (both commercial & open source) for multiple operating systems.

One interesting software project which is not on that list yet is [Ramen](http://ramencomp.blogspot.com/) that is designed for 64 bits Linux operating systems.

Comment: +1 for Ramen.  That one is new to me.  I would also throw Blender into the mix.  While it's better known as a 3d animation tool it also includes a node based compositor and NLE.

Comment: Do you work with any of this @JanC ?

Comment: Ramen seems dead as of 2022

Answer (score 5):

Although this is a rather old question, for the benefit of new users / searchers, I think [blender](http://www.blender.org) needs a more prominent place in the answers than as in a comment.
With the finalization of [project mango](http://mango.blender.org/), called *Tears of Steel*, blenders abilities in regard to post production are stronger than ever -- the node based compositor is very powerful indeed. You need to get used to blender, but it's worth it.

Update: Blender 2.69 was just released a couple of days ago, with many improvements in camera tracking, motion tracking, ...

Answer (score 3):

I've been an After Effects user for 12+ years and I have not found anything really comparable on linux platforms. Cinelerra is probably the closest and looks promising, but I have little experience with it (basically since my clients are dedicated to AE). The other apps listed by others above are primarily video editors; and as I'm sure you're aware, that is not After Effects primary niche.

[Cinepaint](http://www.cinepaint.org/about.html), developed for the motion picture industry says that they may eventually add features in the direction of AE.

Answer (score 2):

There's PiTiVi which is included by default. And there is [LightWorks](http://www.editshare.com/index.php?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=208) which is opensource.

Comment: PiTiVi is not up to the level of After Effects but Cinelerra is.

Comment: LightWorks is not available yet, and I am starting to wonder if it ever will be...

Comment: cinelerra is really nice.

Comment: PiTiVi is a editor tool as Final Cut Pro. This answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives, [see here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1541844).

When looking for applications, don't forget to search/browse the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Also there is a website (*http://www.osalt.com*) that compares proprietary and open source software.

Comment: Also, there is a list of sites to help you find alternatives [here](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/684/where-can-i-find-alternatives-to)